# Spring Caching: Invalidate lists containing updated/deleted element

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm just new to implement caching with Spring and Ehcache. I got stucked on the following issue: 
Let's say we've got a cache named "projectCache", containing single instances as well as collections of the Project domain class. If an already cached project gets updated, I want to make sure that not just the project entry itself **but also every list containing this object is removed from the cache**.

The most simple solution may be to invalidate the whole "projectCache" cache, but that should be avoided as far as possible:

```
@CacheEvict(value="projectCache")
```

I already read about Ehcache providing search attributes via its API. However, is there a way to achieve my goal relying on Spring?